# C# OpenFileDialog open zip folder containing single file?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, encryption, openfiledialog

I have an application which currently provides the user with the ability to view a PDF file inside the application by using File->Open, browsing to the location of the PDF file using a `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`, and then displaying that PDF file in a `System.Windows.Controls.WebBrowser` in the GUI.

I am creating the `OpenFileDialog` and setting the file extensions it can open using:

```
/*Create Open File dialog */
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog OFDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        /*Set filter for file extension and default file extension */
        OFDlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
        OFDlg.Filter = "PDF Documents (.pdf)|*.pdf";
```

I now want to extend this, so that the user can open a ZIP folder containing a single PDF document, and display that PDF document in the same way that I am above.

I tried changing the filter to allow .zip files, i.e.

```
OFDlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf|.zip";
OFDlg.Filter = "PDF Documents (.pdf)|*.pdf|ZIP|*.zip";
```

but when I browse to the location of the .zip file in the `OpenFileDialog`, the .zip folder is not displayed there- only normal folders and PDF documents (other documents in that directory, such as .doc & .xls are not displayed in the `OpenFileDialog`).

My reason for wanting to be able to open the contents of a .zip file directly from the .zip, rather than navigating to that file itself, is so that I can add public/private key encryption to the .zip, so that its contents can only be read securely.

I know that there could in theory be problems if the .zip contains more than one file, but I intend to send each encrypted file in its own zip folder, so it can be assumed that any zip file that the user is trying to open contains a single .pdf, and nothing else.

So my questions are:

1. How can I make .zip folders visible from the `OpenFileDialog`?
2. How can I make the selection of that .zip folder automatically open and display its contents (a single PDF file) in the `System.Window.Controls.WebBrowser` that I am currently using to display PDFs in my GUI?

**Edit 1**

I tried changing  my `OpenFile()` method to the following code:

```
/*Set filter for file extension and default file extension */
        OFDlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf";
        OFDlg.DefaultExt = ".zip";
        OFDlg.Filter = "PDF Documents (.pdf)|*.pdf";
        OFDlg.Filter = "ZIP Folders (.ZIP)|*.zip";
```

but when I now run my application, and browse to the same location, although the .zip folder is now shown in the `OpenFileDialog`, the .pdf files no longer are... and if I double click the .zip folder, my application breaks, and I get a runtime error on the line

```
PdfPanel.OpenFile(docFP);
```

which says:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in MoonPdfLib.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I guess that's to do with the MoonPDF library that I'm using to read the PDFs being unable to handle the .zip extension?

How would I resolve this to be able to open the PDF inside the ZIP?

**Edit 2**

Ok, so I've resolved the issue about only being able to see either the PDF files or the .ZIP folders (not both at the same time), by moving the functionality into two separate methods- one to display the PDF direct from the PDF's filepath, and another to display the PDF from the path of the .ZIP folder holding it.

The method for displaying the PDFs directly currently works (it is essentially the code in the first bit of code I've quoted). However the method for displaying the PDFs from the ZIP currently doesn't work...

I understand the reason for this- it's because I am passing a `.zip` folder to the `OpenFile` method... The code for this method currently looks like this:

```
private void openZipMenuItem_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog OZipDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        OZipDlg.DefaultExt = ".zip";
        OZipDlg.Filter = "ZIP Folder (.zip)|*.zip";

        Nullable<bool> result = OZipDlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {
            /*Open document */
            string filename = OZipDlg.FileName;
            //fnTextBox.Text = filename;
            zipFP = OZipDlg.FileName;
            /*browser.Navigate(docFP); ERF (27/05/2016 @ 0935) Comment this line- I want to use PdfPanel to open docFP, not browser */

            Console.WriteLine("Panel height: " + PdfPanel.ActualHeight);
            PdfPanel.OpenFile(zipFP);

        }
    }
```

When I try to call this function to open a .zip, I get a runtime exception which says:

> AccessViolationException was unhandled
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in MoonPdfLib.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I understand that I can't display a Zip folder in the `PdfPanel` (which is a `MoonPdfPanel` that I am using from the `MoonPdfLibrary`), so I know that I will get an exception here.

How can I pass the contents of `zipFP` to the call to `PdfPanel.OpenFile()`, rather than passing `zipFP` itself to it?

**Edit 3**

Ok, so my code is currently extracting the PDF file successfully from the ZIP folder when I open it- I can see that it is copied to the directory I have specified. I am now trying to get the PDF to be displayed automatically in the PDF Panel on my application- I've done this by adding the following code:

```
try{
    string extractPath = @"C:\Documents";
    using(ZipArchivev zip = ZipFile.Open(zipFP, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries){
            try{
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFP, extractPath);
                Console.WriteLine("zipFP: " + zipFP);
            }catch(System.IOException){
                Console.WriteLine("File already exists...");
            }
        }

        string ExtractedPDF = string.Concat(extractPath, zipFP);
        PdfPanel.OpenFile(ExtractedPDF);
}catch(AccessViolationException ex){
    Console.WriteLine("Can't display a zip in the PDF panel..." + ex.InnerException);
}
```

But when my code tries to execute the line `PdfPanel.OpenFile(ExtracedPDF);`, I get an exception that says:

> FileNotFoundException was unhandled | An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in MoonPdfLib.dll'

I understand that this is happening because the variable I am trying to display in the PDFPanel, `ExtractedPDF` actually holds the path of the folder containing the PDF, and not the PDF itself- How do I give it the name of the PDF file, when I don't actually know what the PDF file will be called?

Comment: The filter you added should add two options to the File Type combobox in the open dialog - one for PDFs, and one for zip files. If you select the option for zip files, does that cause the zip files to be shown in the dialog?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment- yep, I thought of this just after posting, and tried it, but by doing that, the `OpenFileDialog` no longer shows me the PDF files that are there, although it does now show the ZIP folders in that location. I've updated my OP to reflect the issues I get as a result of trying that.

Comment: In your first example you have `OFDlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf|.zip";`. That's an error. `DefaultExt` expects a single extension: the one that will be used by default when the dialog is first displayed. It should be either ".pdf" or ".zip".  The access violation is probably because you're trying to open a .zip file as though it's a PDF. That's not going to end well.

Comment: You can add all of the filters in one line (PDF and ZIP). You also have a property to set the default file type and the initial filter index selected.

Comment: Sounds like you want to know how to open a ZIP file to get at the PDF files held inside it.

Comment: As I've mentioned in the second edit to my OP, I've moved the functionality to open Zips/ PDFs into two separate methods- so I no longer have the line `OFDlg.DefaultExt = ".pdf|.zip";`, I have one method for reading PDFs, and another for reading ZIPs.

Comment: Andrew Truckle- that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Are you trying to do what [this user wants to prevent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919773/c-sharp-prevent-openfiledialog-to-display-zipentries-of-a-zip-file)?

Comment: Bolu, no- I'm trying to give the application a .zip folder (which I know contains a single PDF file, and nothing else), and display that PDF file in the `WebBrowser` in my application.

Comment: check my answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something works similar to your requests, the logic behind the code is:

- Only display zip and pdf files in the `OpenFileDialog`
- If user selected a pdf file, show it in the panel
- If user selected a zip file, change the directory of the `OpenFileDialog` to the zip file(treat it like a folder)

Example code (working code....):

```
 OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
 ofd.Filter = "PDF files (.pdf)|*.pdf;*.zip";
 ofd.ShowDialog();

 //reopen OpenFileDialog if it is zip file. this part can be improved.
 if (ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".zip")) 
 {
     ofd.InitialDirectory = ofd.FileName;
     ofd.ShowDialog();
 }

 //if it's a PDF, note that you don't really need this check, 
 //as the only file can reache here will be a PDF, 
 //and it can be the temporary file that inside a zip. 
 if(ofd.FileName.EndsWith(".pdf"))
 {
    //show it in your PdfPanel
 }
```

Edit, based on your new comments and added code. you need to change your code to the following as your current code is mistaken directory with the file:

```
try{
    string extractPath = @"C:\Documents";
    string ExtractedPDF ="";
    using(ZipArchivev zip = ZipFile.Open(zipFP, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
        foreach(ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries){
            try{
                ExtractedPDF= Path.Combine(extractPath, entry.FullName);
                entry.ExtractToFile(ExtractedPDF,true);

            }catch(System.IOException){
                Console.WriteLine("error during extraction...");
            }
        } 
        if( System.IO.File.Exists(ExtractedPDF))
        {
             PdfPanel.OpenFile(ExtractedPDF);
        }
}catch(AccessViolationException ex){
    Console.WriteLine("Can't display a zip in the PDF panel..." + ex.InnerException);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bolu. I have code very similar to that, but while debugging it, when it gets to the line `PdfPanel.OpenFile(ExtractedPDF);`, and tries to execute that line, I get an exception that says: `FileNotFoundException was unhandled`... The message below it says: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in MoonPdfLib.dll`... MoonPDF is the library that I am using to display PDF files on the panel in my GUI...

Comment: Have you checked if `ExtractedPDF` does exist on your local drive? If it comes from a zip file, it will be located in a temporary folder (e.g.C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\zxczcxxx\xxx.pdf).

Comment: I've just updated my OP- I think the issue is that `ExtractedPDF` is holding the path/name for the folder containing the PDF, not the PDF itself- is there a way that I can get the PDF inside that folder, so I can pass its name to the variable?

Comment: The PDF file does exist on my local drive- as I am successfully extracting it.

Comment: I had no idea you could get OpenFileDialog to step inside the zip file by setting InitialDirectory. That saved me a lot of work, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to support multiple file formats in an open file dialog, you need to add a third (or better first) option, that aggregates all supported file extensions:

```
OFDlg.Filter = "Supported file formats|*.pdf;*.zip|PDF Documents|*.pdf|ZIP files|*.zip";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, regarding showing the files in the open file dialog. Your initial method for doing this was correct. Your updated code now first sets the filter to show PDFs, then replaces that filter with one that shows zip files. The standard file open dialog isn't designed to show different file types at the same time. The right way to handle that is to give the user the option for which file types they want to show.

Typically, an "All files" option is added as well (with *.* as the search pattern). This way if the file type the user wants to open isn't available in the list, they can see it regardless.

As for opening the PDF file that is in the zip file, you need to take are of extracting the PDF file yourself. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296918/how-to-extract-zip-file-in-c-sharp) has some options for how to do that.