# Moving compressed file from one computer to another

Tags: c#, ftp

My project is FTP, and I need some help.
1. I'm using Huffman Code to compress file and then send it to the computer that is asking the file.

The function from the huffman code returns byte array.
I don't understand how to send the bytes.

I have this function:

```
    private void UpLoad(string namefile)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInfo ftemp = new FileInfo(ClientForm.SharedFolderPath + "\\" + namefile);   // file name
            long total = ftemp.Length;              // size of file in long
            long rdby = 0;
            int len = 0;                            // the numbers of bytes to read

            byte[] buffed = new byte[1024];
            //Open the file requested for download 
            FileStream fin = new FileStream(ClientForm.SharedFolderPath + "\\" + namefile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            //One way of transfer over sockets is Using a NetworkStream 
            //It provides some useful ways to transfer data 
            NetworkStream nfs = client.GetStream();

            //lock the Thread here
            lock (this)
            {
                while (rdby < total && nfs.CanWrite)
                {
                    //Read from the File (len contains the number of bytes read)
                    len = fin.Read(buffed, 0, buffed.Length);
                    //wait for downloader..
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                    //Write the Bytes on the Socket
                    nfs.Write(buffed, 0, len);
                    //Increase the bytes Read counter
                    rdby = rdby + len;
                }
                //Display a Message Showing Sucessful File Transfer
                fin.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ed)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ed.Message);
        }
    }
```

Can someone help me please?

1. I need to identify when the file is compressed and if its not, I need to compress it.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Can't you just check the file extension and look for .zip or something similar?

Comment: I wish, my Lecturer bind me for checking the first bytes of the file..

Comment: This question might help, the first byte is usually set to a magic number for zip files, this isn't always the case though:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996299/c-net-identify-zip-file

Comment: but how i can be sure that the file is zip? what if its JPEG or PNG or even WMA?

Comment: Generally you can determine uncompressible/bad compressible files by calculating their entropy.